# Best method about sessions with express / node.js

Tags: javascript, session, express

I started using `express` and `node.js`about a login/signup + sessions system for an dashboard project. I've already created and integrated login and signup functions to my dashboard. What I'm missing is **sessions**.

I'm asking there which method(s) is/are the best secure to implement with express 4.14. I know there are plenty of articles and guides about creating sessions with JWT and cookies, but some ppl says that JWT are terrible security talking, and other telling the same thing about cookies.. well I'm confused.

What I'm looking for is not necessarily pieces of code, but much more a solution, a method, etc.

Comment: Opinion questions do not belong on SO. I can however say that JWTs are more popular for applications where the frontend is strictly seperated and all the requests happen asynchronously because it is clearer when it is sent.

Comment: JWT are great, if you need decentralized "sessions" and/or support for clients without cookies, otherwise, the regular cookie based session will work just fine.

Comment: Okay thanks, i think i'll just stick with cookies then